# NullPointerException while creating Data source in IBM WebSphere

Tags: websphere, datasource, ojdbc

I am trying to create a data source to an OJDBC on IBM WebSphere and when I tried to test the connection, I got the error as shown below:
I have doubled check to ensure that all inputs are filled correctly when setting up.

```
00000100 DataSourceCon E   DSRA8040I: Failed to connect to the DataSource "".  Encountered java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigHelper$1.run(DSConfigHelper.java:1273)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5486)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.ServerFunction$6.run(ServerFunction.java:567)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigHelper.getPooledConnection(DSConfigHelper.java:1288)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigHelper.getPooledConnection(DSConfigHelper.java:1196)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.getConnectionFromDSOrPooledDS(DSConfigurationHelper.java:2076)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.getConnectionFromDSOrPooledDS(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1952)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.testConnectionForGUI(DSConfigurationHelper.java:2820)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor465.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.testConnectionToDataSource2(DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.java:556)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.testConnection(DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.java:484)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor463.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:292)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1261)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:422)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:88)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1255)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1093)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:832)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:814)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$QueuedWork.run(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1987)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

I would appreciate if anyone could provide me some assistance and let me know what is causing this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would try restarting your server to see if that resolves the test connection.  Otherwise it seems something may be incorrect with your configuration.  The following link lists some of the configuration issues that can lead to a null pointer exception during test connection:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21177990

Comment: Hi, I restarted my server and it did resolve the error! Thanks so much!